# problem in installing ad-hoc1 provision on device

Tags: iphone, installation

i am having problem in installing provision it gies me error that "A validcode signing identity is not found in your keychain" I have tried all the possble soluton given on app.dev.troubleshooting and also on stackoverflow.com. My device before had 3.1.1 OS but it was not supprted by my Xcode version so i installed #.0 on device. so is it might be the coz?
I have chekced all my certificate and WWDR all certificates are valid. I tried everything restarting device, checking code signing identity but its not wrking. still givesthe same err

Comment: This seems like a Superuser.com question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it not working only for the AdHoc build?

Did you create the distribution build setting?

Assign it the right code signing identity?

Did you set the proper identity string in the "properties" tab of the active target info? It should be com.YOURNAME.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

All those steps are well explained at [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action).

Answer (score 0):

@sam
i have another profile also but that was created for other device. and this device does not suprt thet profile.Main thing is this is not my device so i got provision also when i got device. in code signing identity it gives that cannot find anyprivate key orcertificate supprting this profile. so option for ahoc is disabled only. so am not geting what to do.
and link you given is not found can you specify the URL